# Подключение к Oracle на Python

Tags: python, oracle

Какую библиотеку можно использовать для подключения к Oracle на Python?
Знаю, что есть cx_Oracle, но у меня она не работает, выдает ошибку:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at version 11.2 or higher

```
import cx_Oracle

conn = cx_Oracle('jdbc:oracle:thin:tst/tst@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = e-scan)(PORT = " \
             "1521))(CONNECT_DATA " \
             "=(SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = snm))))')
```

> Oracle Instant Client распаковала в (C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_2), прописала в ORACLE_HOME, PATH.

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75988/discussion-on-question-by-alia---oracle--python).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка:

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: DPI-1050: Oracle Client library must be at
>   version 11.2 or higher

указывает, что `cx_Oracle` пытается использовать старую (неподдерживаюмую) версию `Oracle [Instant] Client`.

---

[Требования для cx_Oracle **6.x**](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#overview):

- Python 2.7 or 3.4 and higher. Older versions of cx_Oracle may work with older versions of Python.
- [Oracle Client libraries](http://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/installation.html#oracle-client-and-oracle-database-interoperability). These can be from the free Oracle Instant Client, or those included in Oracle Database if Python is on the same machine as the database. Oracle client libraries versions **12.2**, **12.1** and **11.2** are supported on Linux, Windows and macOS. Users have also reported success with other platforms.
- An Oracle Database. Oracle’s standard client-server version interoperability allows cx_Oracle to connect to both older and newer databases.

Платформа ("битность") Python и cx_Oracle должны совпадать - или **оба** пакета `64-bit` или оба - `32-bit`.

Также, надо прописать соответствующий путь к Oracle Client в переменных окружения `ORACLE_HOME` и `PATH`.

Например, в диалоговом окне **Переменные среды** Windows:

```
PATH:  C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_2;...

ORACLE_HOME: C:\Oracle\instantclient_12_2
```